# How to Automate selecting values in a iOS PickerWheel with Ruby

Tags: ios, ruby, automation, cucumber

I have been automating an application with Ruby and the Cucumber Framework. I'm utilizing XCUITest for my iOS automation within this framework.

From what research I've done it appears as though I have to send text to the picker wheel for it to adjust to the wanted value. This is the code I've tried to use:

```
Then(/^I click on month"([^"]*)"$/) do |month_number|
  find_element(xpath: "//XCUIElementTypePickerWheel[1]").adjustToPickerWheelValue("#{month_number}")
end
```

With this code my Cucumber framework calls the find_element method for that element and attempts to send the "month_number" value to a "adjustToPickerWheelValue" method.

The error I receive when I attempt to use this method is a standard noMethod error:

```
undefined method `adjustToPickerWheelValue' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x007f802cda98d8> (NoMethodError)
```

Is there something special I need to do to call this method in my env.rb file? Right now I just have "appium_lib" as required. Is there an XCUITest library I need to be utilizing as well?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to automating iOS. Thanks for reading and I hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: So I did a little more research and it appears as though they fixed this with a new method "selectPickerWheelValue". My problem now is that my automation environment doesn't seem to utilize the method correctly.

I get the following error `Unknown mobile command "selectPickerWheelValue". Only scroll, swipe, pinch, doubleTap, twoFinterTap, touchAndHold, tap, dragFromToForDuration commands are supported`

What am I missing in my environment that would allow me to utilize this method from the appium-xcuitest-driver?

Answer (score 0):

The method  for xcuitest is

```
select_picker_wheel(element:, order:, offset: nil)
```